# How to change multiple filenames preserving variable part of the name in linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, rename, batch-rename

I have thousands of filenames with this regular expression:

```regex
(sp|li)_(test|train|val)_(loss|acc)_((1e-\d+)|(0[.]0{0,4}1))_curious_\d+_plasticity[.]npy
```

Examples of it are:

```
li_test_acc_0.01_curious_1_plasticity.npy
li_test_acc_0.0001_curious_1_plasticity.npy
sp_train_loss_1e-05_curious_901_plasticity.npy
```

I want to remove **`curious`** and substitute it with **`plasticity`** which is in the end, as the new regular expression of names will be:

```regex
(sp|li)_(test|train|val)_(loss|acc)_((1e-\d+)|(0[.]0{0,4}1))_plasticity_\d+[.]npy
```

That the names change to:

```
li_test_acc_0.01_plasticity_1.npy
li_test_acc_0.0001_plasticity_1.npy
sp_train_loss_1e-05_plasticity_901.npy
```

---

I have seen few solutions using `rename` to do so as in [here](https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-rename-multiple-files-at-once-in-linux/). But these solutions do not preserve the other parts of the name. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rename` solution should work, if it is the "Perl rename" (which is `rename` on Debian and derivatives, but `prename` on Redhat and derivatives). This can be checked with `[p]rename --version` that should answer:

```
/usr/bin/rename using File::Rename version 0.20
```

Given the right `rename` then it is a simple matter of:

```
rename -n 's/curious_(\d+)_plasticity\.npy$/plasticity_$1.npy/' *.npy
```

In otherwords

- in file names ending with:

  - "curious"
  - an underscore
  - some digits
  - another underscore
  - "plasticity"
  - the ".npy" extension
- replace "curious" and following by:

  - "plasticity"
  - an underscore
  - the group of digits found
  - the ".npy" extension

`-n` is for dry runs, remove or replace with `-v` for actual execution.

```
$>>rename -n 's/curious_(\d+)_plasticity\.npy$/plasticity_$1.npy/' *.npy
rename(li_test_acc_0.01_curious_1_plasticity.npy, li_test_acc_0.01_plasticity_1.npy)
```

Comment: Thank you. Comprehensive and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
for file in $(ls | grep -e '\(sp\|li\)_\(test\|train\|val\)_\(loss\|acc\)_\(\(1e-[0-9]\+\)\|\(0[.]0\{0,4\}1\)\)_curious_[0-9]\+_plasticity[.]npy'); do mv $file $(echo $file | sed 's/\(.*\)curious\(.*\)_plasticity\(.*\)/\1plasticity\2\3/g'); done
```

(the exact syntax depending on your shell obviously).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.